# gMap marker precision

Tags: jquery, google-maps, dictionary, google-maps-api-3, jquery-gmap

I use gMap to indicate office marker on google map inside my website as below :

```
var mapMarkers = [{
        address: "36.2929949,59.5837028501",
        html: "<strong style='float:right'>Blah</strong><br>Blah, Blah Blah<br><br><a href='#' onclick='mapCenterAt({latitude: 36.2929949, longitude: 59.5837028501, zoom: 19}, event)'>[+] Center</a>",
        icon: {
            image: "images/pin.png",
            iconsize: [33, 33],
            iconanchor: [33, 33]
        }
    }];

    // Map Initial Location
    var initLatitude = 36.2929949;
    var initLongitude = 59.5837028501;


    // Map Extended Settings
    var mapSettings = {
        controls: {
            panControl: true,
            zoomControl: false,
            mapTypeControl: true,
            scaleControl: true,
            streetViewControl: false,
            overviewMapControl: true
        },
        scrollwheel: false,
        markers: mapMarkers,
        latitude: initLatitude,
        longitude: initLongitude,
        zoom: 19
    };
var map = $("#googlemaps").gMap(mapSettings),
        mapRef = $("#googlemaps").data('gMap.reference');

    // Map Center At
    var mapCenterAt = function (options, e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#googlemaps").gMap("centerAt", options);
    }
```

but when I feel it rounds Latitude and Longitude . I can't pin it exactly where I want.

[image]

I can't pin between this two points.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you think that change is moving the marker appreciably?  More likely that your custom icon is defined incorrectly.

Comment: I've updated my question with images

Comment: Try making your coordinates equal in length `36.2929949000,59.5837028501`

Comment: What library are you using?

Answer (score 1):

the difference between these 2 latlngs is very small,(when I say small I talk about micrometer or nanometer).

You may assume a precision of 1 meter with 5 decimals, a difference of 0.0000000001 will have no visible effect, because there is no zoom-level which may represent the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Provide the coordinates, not an address containing the coordinates.

From the [documentation](https://hpneo.github.io/gmaps/examples/markers.html)

```
map.addMarker({
  lat: -12.043333,
  lng: -77.028333,
  title: 'Lima',
  click: function(e) {
    alert('You clicked in this marker');
  }
});
```

So this should work:

```
var mapMarkers = [{
    lat: 36.2929949,
    lng: 59.5837028501",
    html: "<strong style='float:right'>Blah</strong><br>Blah, Blah Blah<br><br><a href='#' onclick='mapCenterAt({latitude: 36.2929949, longitude: 59.5837028501, zoom: 19}, event)'>[+] Center</a>",
    icon: {
        image: "images/pin.png",
        iconsize: [33, 33],
        iconanchor: [33, 33]
    }
}];
```

When you provide an "address", GMaps uses the Geocoder, which will return the closest reverse geocoder result, which changes when you change the resolution of the coordinates.

[Google Maps API v3 reverse geocoder results for the two points of interest](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_example_geo2.asp?addr1=36.2929949,59.5837028501&addr2=36.2929949,59.583702850&geocode=1&geocode=2)